# Ubuntu 16.04: secure boot

Tags: boot

In my PC secure boot is enabled.
I successfully installed 16.04 (desktop). 
But during the installation I was not asked to enter a security key.
So how the grub, kernel was signed ?

Thank you,
Zvika

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu kernels are signed and you can install Ubuntu with Secure Boot enabled.

But you can't install 3rd party drivers with SB on.

Comment: Hi. I installed grub2 with: sudo grub-install --uefi-secure-boot --efi-directory=/mnt --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdc. grub2 is working . But how grub2  was signed without knowing what is the key ?  Best regards.

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot OS never "asks" for a key.

Comment: Hi. According to the link If I want to use the firmware keys I must use MokManager instead of grub. Am I right ? Best regards. Zvika

Comment: You don't need to use anything to install Ubuntu.